# Running console command from a Symfony 2 test case

Tags: php, symfony

Is there a way to run a console command from a Symfony 2 test case? I want to run the doctrine commands for creating and dropping schemas.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The documentation has been updated since my last answer to reflect the proper Symfony 2 way of calling an existing command:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command

Comment: It is not true Symfony way

Comment: It's not even a good way as you cannot parse the ouptut correctly. You also might run into problems with the environment (what if php is not in the path of the user running the tests?).

Comment: Please, don't do it this way!

Comment: Note that the original question is not about testing commands, but about executing commands during tests. Like droping / recreating datas, validating users without email validation, etc. Please read carefully before downgrading.

Answer (score 76):

This [documentation chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html#calling-an-existing-command) explains how to run commands from different places. Mind, that using `exec()` for your needs is quite dirty solution...

The **right way** of executing console command in Symfony2 is as below:

## Option one

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application as App;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class YourTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = $this->createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $application = new App($kernel);
        $application->add(new YourCommand());

        $command = $application->find('your:command:name');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(array('command' => $command->getName()));
    }
}
```

---

## Option two

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;

class YourClass extends WebTestCase
{
    protected static $application;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::runCommand('your:command:name');
        // you can also specify an environment:
        // self::runCommand('your:command:name --env=test');
    }

    protected static function runCommand($command)
    {
        $command = sprintf('%s --quiet', $command);    

        return self::getApplication()->run(new StringInput($command));
    }

    protected static function getApplication()
    {
        if (null === self::$application) {
            $client = static::createClient();

            self::$application = new Application($client->getKernel());
            self::$application->setAutoExit(false);
        }

        return self::$application;
    }
}
```

---

*P.S. Guys, don't shame Symfony2 with calling `exec()`...*

Comment: This is the right answer as mentioned on the official Symfony2 documentantion under "Testing Commands": http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#testing-commands

Comment: @FrancescoCasula link is broken - new location: http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#testing-commands

Answer (score 5):

The [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command) tell you the suggested way to do it. The example code is pasted below:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');

    $arguments = array(
        'command' => 'demo:greet',
        'name'    => 'Fabien',
        '--yell'  => true,
    );

    $input = new ArrayInput($arguments);
    $returnCode = $command->run($input, $output);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is for running a command from another command, not from a test case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if your directory structure looks like

```
/symfony
    /app
    /src
```

then you would run

`phpunit -c app/phpunit.xml.dist`

from your unit tests you can run php commands either by using

```
passthru("php app/console [...]") (http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php)
exec("php app/console [...]") (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
```

or by putting the command in back ticks

`php app/consode [...]`

If you are running the unit tests from a directory other than symofny, you'll have to adjust the relative path to the app directory for it to work.

To run it from the app:

```
// the document root should be the web folder
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

passthru("php $root/../app/console [...]");
```

Comment: Isn't there a way of running from inside the application? I'm trying to create completely isolated tests.

Comment: Also, i want the command to run on a specific environment (test).

Comment: Yes, you could put that code inside a model or entity, but you would have to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to get the path to app. I'll edit my answer

Comment: im not sure how to access the environment from the app, but if there's a way you can do it, just put the passthru inside an if statement that checks for the environment

Comment: exec() won't work since it won't be in the test container.