# How can I run symfony 2 run command from controller

Tags: symfony, controller, command

I'm wondering how can I run **Symfony 2** command from browser query or from controller.

Its because I don't have any possibility on hosting to run it and every cron jobs are setted by admin.

I don't even have enabled `exec()` function so when I want to test it, I must copy all content from command to some testing controller and this is not best solution.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

See [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) on this issue for newer versions of Symfony

---

You don't need services for command execution from controller and, I think, it is better to call command via `run` method and not via console string input, however [official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command) suggest you to call command via it's alias. Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11755640/541961). Tested on Symfony 2.1-2.6.

Your command class must extend `ContainerAwareCommand`

```
// Your command

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;

class MyCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
    // …
}


// Your controller

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;

class SomeController extends Controller {

    // …

    public function myAction()
    {
        $command = new MyCommand();
        $command->setContainer($this->container);
        $input = new ArrayInput(array('some-param' => 10, '--some-option' => true));
        $output = new NullOutput();
        $resultCode = $command->run($input, $output);
    }
}
```

In most cases you don't need `BufferedOutput` (from **Jbm's** answer) and it is enough to check that `$resultCode is 0`, otherwise there was an error.

Comment: I don't get a `setContainer` method in 2.4

Comment: You also need to put the executed command name as first element of the `ArrayInput` (at least on Symfony2.6).

Comment: If the command is time-consuming you'll probably need to increase the execution time in order to avoid a timeout:  `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);` as well.

Comment: This feels totally overcomplicated what Symfony forces the developer to do here... I mean seriously :)

Answer (score 57):

Register your command as a service and don't forget to call `setContainer`

```
MyCommandService:
    class: MyBundle\Command\MyCommand
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]
```

In your controller, you'll just have to get this service, and call the execute method with the rights arguments

Set the input with `setArgument` method:

```
$input = new Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput([]);
$input->setArgument('arg1', 'value');
$output = new Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput();
```

Call the `run` method of the command:

```
$command = $this->get('MyCommandService');
$command->run($input, $output);
```

Comment: $output var is for capture the console reply? Thanks

Comment: yes, there is a `writeLine` method to write a line in the console

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!
Still, I had some issues wrapping doctrine:generate:entity Command in a service. Because of:
  1) The Command's HelperSet being null.
  2) The isInteractive being true.

Solutions:
1) in my service's constructor I instantiated an Application and passed it's helperSet to the Command:
`$application = new Symfony\Component\Console\Application();`
`$this->doctrineGenEntityCmd->setHelperSet($application->getHelperSet());`

2) 
`$input->setInteractive(false)`

Answer (score 10):

In my environment  ( Symony 2.1 ) I had to do some modifications to @Reuven solution to make it work. Here they are:

Service definition - no changes.

In controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

...

public function myAction() {
    $command = $this->get('MyCommandService');

    $input = new ArgvInput(array('arg1'=> 'value'));
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();

    $command->run($input, $output);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just simply create an instance of your command and run it:

```
/**
 * @Route("/run-command")
 */
public function someAction()
{
    // Running the command
    $command = new YourCommand();
    $command->setContainer($this->container);

    $input = new ArrayInput(['--your_argument' => true]);
    $output = new ConsoleOutput();

    $command->run($input, $output);

    return new Response();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative that lets you execute commands as strings the same way you would on the console (there is no need for defining services with this one).

You can check [this bundle's controller](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle/blob/master/Controller/ConsoleController.php) to see how it's done with all the details. Here I'm going to summarize it ommiting certain details (such as handling the environment, so here all commands will run in the same environment they are invoked).

If you want to just run commands from the browser, you can use that bundle as it is, but if you want to run commands from an arbitrary controller here is how to do it:

In your controller define a function like this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\StringInput;

private function execute($command)
{
    $app = new Application($this->get('kernel'));
    $app->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new StringInput($command);
    $output = new BufferedOutput();

    $error = $app->run($input, $output);

    if($error != 0)
        $msg = "Error: $error";
    else
        $msg = $output->getBuffer();
    return $msg;
}
```

Then you can invoke it from an action like this:

```
public function dumpassetsAction()
{
    $output = $this->execute('assetic:dump');

    return new Response($output);
}
```

Also, you need to define a class to act as output buffer, because there is none provided by the framework:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Output;

class BufferedOutput extends Output
{
    public function doWrite($message, $newline)
    {
        $this->buffer .= $message. ($newline? PHP_EOL: '');
    }

    public function getBuffer()
    {
        return $this->buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also a quite nice implementation in the LiipFunctionalTestBundle that uses php://temp stream with the built in StreamOutput class to capture the output so you don't need to create a second output buffer class yourself.
https://github.com/liip/LiipFunctionalTestBundle/blob/master/Test/WebTestCase.php#L102

Comment: Just a note to say that `BufferedOutput` is now available since Symfony 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

same as @malloc
but

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;

...

public function myAction() {
  $command = $this->get('MyCommandService');

  // $input[0] : command name
  // $input[1] : argument1
  $input = new ArgvInput(array('my:command', 'arg1'));
  $output = new ConsoleOutput();

  $command->run($input, $output);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to pass arguments (and/or options), then in v2.0.12 (and may be true for later versions), you need to specify InputDefinition first before instantiating an input object.

```
use // you will need the following
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput,
    Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;


// tell symfony what to expect in the input
$inputDefinition = new InputDefinition(array(
    new InputArgument('myArg1', InputArgument::REQUIRED),
    new InputArgument('myArg2', InputArgument::REQUIRED),
    new InputOption('debug', '0', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL),
));


// then pass the values for arguments to constructor, however make sure 
// first param is dummy value (there is an array_shift() in ArgvInput's constructor)
$input = new ArgvInput(
                        array(
                                'dummySoInputValidates' => 'dummy', 
                                'myArg2' => 'myValue1', 
                                'myArg2' => 'myValue2'), 
                        $inputDefinition);
$output = new NullOutput();
```

As a side note, if you are using if you are using getContainer() in your command, then the following function may be handy for your command.php:

```
/**
 * Inject a dependency injection container, this is used when using the 
 * command as a service
 * 
 */
function setContainer(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface $container = null)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}

/**
 * Since we are using command as a service, getContainer() is not available
 * hence we need to pass the container (via services.yml) and use this function to switch
 * between conatiners..
 *
 */
public function getcontainer()
{
    if (is_object($this->container))
        return $this->container;

    return parent::getcontainer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this bundle to run Symfony2 commands from controller (http request) and pass options/parameters in URL.

https://github.com/mrafalko/CommandRunnerBundle

Answer (score 0):

If you run a command that need the `env` option like `assetic:dump`

```
$stdout->writeln(sprintf('Dumping all <comment>%s</comment> assets.', $input->getOption('env')));
```

You have to create a `Symfony\Component\Console\Application` and set the definition like that:

```
use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputDefinition;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOuput;

// Create and run the command of assetic
$app = new Application();
$app->setDefinition(new InputDefinition([
    new InputOption('env', '', InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, '', 'prod')
]));
$app->add(new DumpCommand());

/** @var DumpCommand $command */
$command = $app->find('assetic:dump');
$command->setContainer($this->container);
$input = new ArgvInput([
    'command' => 'assetic:dump',
    'write_to' => $this->assetsDir
]);
$output = new NullOutput();
$command->run($input, $output);
```

You can't set the option `env` to the command because it isn't in its definition.

Comment: Silex Application extends Pimple Container and implements HttpKernelInterface, TerminableInterface, and has no `setDefinition` method.