# Email doesn't send in Swiftmailer Symfony2

Tags: php, email, symfony, swiftmailer

I use Swiftmailer to send emails in my Symfony 2.5 project. Here is my related code

<kbd>parameters.yml</kbd>

```
parameters:
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: mail.domain.com
mailer_username: user@domain.com
mailer_password: password
mailer_auth_mode:  login
```

<kbd>config.yml</kbd>

```
swiftmailer:
transport: %mailer_transport%
auth_mode:  %mailer_auth_mode%
host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_username%
password:  %mailer_password%
spool:     { type: memory }
```

controller:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('mana')
        ->setFrom('***@gmail.com')
        ->setTo('***@yahoo.com')
        ->setBody('this is test');
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I have swiftmailer in `appKernel.php`

```
$bundles = array(
        ...
        new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
        ...
    );
```

The email did not get sent. Can you help me?

Comment: See [How to send spool from swiftmailer without using command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12369520/2257664).

Comment: Tnx @A.L but in fact i want to send email immediately and spool is not important at all!

Comment: Your problem probably comes from your SMTP server because your code is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code worked in a command but I adapted it for the controller:

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('mana')
    ->setFrom('****@gmail.com')
    ->setTo('mana@yahoo.com')
    ->setBody('this is test');
# I removed this line: $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

$mailer = $this->get('mailer');

$mailer->send($message);

$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $this->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');

$spool->flushQueue($transport);
```

Source : [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/sending_emails.html#using-memory-spooling).

Comment: @MaNa I'm happy it worked for you. But according to the documentation linked in my answer, this code is not necessary if the spooling is properly configured, I suggest you to follow the guidelines from the documentation.

Comment: No email was sent in my service using just send I had to use the flushQueue method for them to finally send. When I ran php app/console swiftmailer:spool:send it said 0 emails is that because my spool type is memory and not file?

Answer (score 0):

config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:  smtp
    encryption: ssl
    auth_mode:  login
    host:       smtp.xx.eu
    username:   username
    password:   password
```

controller/action

```
$messageObject = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Subject')
            ->setFrom('username@xx.eu')
            ->setTo('xxx@stackoverflow.eu')
            ->setBody('message');
$this->get('mailer')->send($messageObject);
```

parameters.yml -default

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
```