# Creating a ready-to-use symfony 2 application zip

Tags: symfony, deployment, assets, assetic

I have created a symfomy application bundle that can be used to collect crash reports from Android applications (for those interested in Android and ACRA: https://github.com/marvinlabs/acra-server).

People who are ok with that can simply install that application as a regular Symfony 2 bundle, by getting it from GitHub and doing all the command line stuff that is needed **BUT** I want people to be able to install that application very simply and without:

- any knowledge of symfony
- requiring access to php composer
- requiring to type any php command line

To do that, I have packaged a zip file containing the whole Symfony code + my bundle. Problem: it seems that the CSS and Javascripts are not properly found, I still need to run a command on the server:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

Question 1: How could I get rid of that last step?

Question 2: Overall, what would you add to my process before making the zip file?

---

Before making that zip file, here is what I do:

- Remove all git folders
- Remove my app/config/parameters.yml file (specific to my dev environment)

I also execute the following commands:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
php app/console doctrine:schema:create --env=dev --dump-sql > create-schema.sql
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --env=dev --dump-sql > update-schema.sql
php app/console assets:install --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

---

PS:

- Demo is there: http://acra-server-demo.marvinlabs.com/dashboard
- Zip file is there: http://www.vincentprat.info/tmp/acra-server-1.0.0.zip (17MB)

---

Instructions to install for those who want to try troubleshooting it:

1. Download http://www.vincentprat.info/tmp/acra-server-1.0.0.zip
2. Upload the zip content on your server
3. Give permissions 777 to directories app/logs and app/cache
4. Create file app/config/parameters.yml from sample file app/config/parameters.yml.dist
5. Create DB tables with help from the file create-schema.sql
6. Make your (sub-)domain point to the directory acra-server/web
7. Access the home page: http://www.example.com/dashboard

---

Edit 12/06/2013

#### Listing of files and permissions right after unzip

```
~/acra-server/web$ ls -l css
total 10
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vincentp users 8990 May 23 18:26 d82d504.css

~/acra-server/web$ ls -l js
total 103
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vincentp users 104721 May 23 18:26 7cb568e.js
```

#### Listing of files and permissions after the assetic dump command

```
:~/acra-server$ ls -l web/js
total 281
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vincentp users 205123 May 28 21:48 7cb568e.js
-rw-r--r--+ 1 vincentp users  21767 May 28 21:48 b96fe74.js
```

We can see that another JS file has been generated (same goes with CSS). I guess Assetic is not looking for the right files out of the unzip. Any idea on how to correct that? Maybe force assetic to use a given filename?

Comment: If it is an option for you, you can consider using [capifony](http://capifony.org/)

Comment: @cheesemacfly Not an option as it would require again command lines. I'd like to stick with a simple FTP upload + SQL script. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dumping to a given filename

( *assetic's output option* )

You are able to configure your asset collection's to dump to a given filename. This can be achieved inside twig with the **output** option. No more auto-generated filenames like *7cb568e.js*.

*example:*

```
{% stylesheets 
    'bundles/mlabsacraserver/stylesheets/*' 
    filter='cssrewrite'
    output='css/stylesheets.css'
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

... or javascripts ...

```
{% javascripts  
    'bundles/mlabsacraserver/js/jquery.min.js'
    'bundles/mlabsacraserver/js/*' 
    output='js/javascripts.js'
%}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

Now assetic will dump your assets to *js/javascripts.js* and *css/stylesheets.css* using the given filters.

The base path where assetic will dump these assets can be configured in your config.yml with **assetic.write_to** and defaults.to the web/ folder.

### pre-configured asset-collections

you can do even better and keep your code more structured.
You can define asset collections inside your config.yml ( or another imported config file ).

The configuration can be found under **assetic.assets**

*example:*

```
# app/config.yml

assetic:
    # ...
    assets:
        js_main:
            inputs:
                - "bundles/mlabsacraserver/js/jquery.min.js"
                - "bundles/mlabsacraserver/js/*"
            output: js/javascripts.js

        css_main:
            inputs:
                - "bundles/mlabsacraserver/stylesheets/*"   
            filters: 
                - cssrewrite                 # ...add more if you like
            output: css/stylesheets.css
```

Now you can use these collections inside your twig templates using assetic's `asset()` function and the `@`-syntax with the corresponding collection names.

*example:*

```
<link href="{{ asset('@css_main') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

... and ...

```
<script src="{{ asset('@js_main') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This way you can configure where assetic shall look for your assets , change the names with a single configuration parameter and keep this logic outside of your templates, making them more readable and easier to maintain.

*example resulting output:*

```
 <link href="/web/css/stylesheets.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="/web/js/javascripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You now have a single configuration point in your application where you add and remove assets using collections and then just use their reference name in your templates.

### further improvements for the deployment

You can have your users enter their MySQL host, user and password and let symfony write the parameters file for you.

This is what the symfony standard-edition does using [SensioDistributionBundle](https://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle) when you first access your application .

The class performing the actual writing of the parameters.yml is [Sensio\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator](https://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle/blob/master/Configurator/Configurator.php).

```
use Sensio\DistributionBundle\Configurator\Configurator;
```

Now use the configurator in your Installation Controller.

```
   $configurator = new Configurator($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir());

   $configurator->mergeParameters(array(
        'my_parameter' = 'my_value',
        'my_parameter2' = 'my_value2',
   ));

  $configurator->write();
}
```

The best thing will be looking at the Configurator class itself to understand how it works.

*can i haz bounty now?* ;-)

Comment: Man, looks like you know everything about symfony! :)

Comment: Good luck! Fabien waiting :)

Comment: You can be first who post out the questions :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31746/discussion-between-forgottenbas-and-nifr)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very detailled answer. I'll explore the various answers which will keep coming till next week before awarding the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

If it not critical to you, its possible do not use assetic at all and not combine all assetic files into one. You lose all features like minify, combining and others. Instead you no longer need to run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`.

To do that - run `php app/console assets:install web`. It copy all your assets to `web/bundles` folder. Then in `base.html.twig` template you can include your assets manually.

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link href="{{ asset('bundles/mlabsacraserverbundle/stylesheets/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    ...
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/mlabsacraserverbundle/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

This is simlpest way to solve your problem.

---

Other way is to call command from php code like described in documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command) and live example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller). You can make an *install* page, where run this command and install assets.

Comment: Well, that's really a last chance method. I'd rather have the users execute the php command. assetic is doing me lots of favours :)

Comment: Other way is to make a settings page where you can dirty exec command like `exec('php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug');` or in more clever way http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html#calling-an-existing-command

Answer (score 0):

What is the html  saying? are your asset paths generated correctly ?

And I see a: 
"php app/console assets:install --env=prod --no-debug"

so actually the css should be there.

Maybe you try the command with your web dir.
wich copies over the css from your Resources/Public folder to your web/bundlename/...

"php app/console assets:install web"

or is it just the same ?

Comment: Css is there, link is in the page when viewed, but somehow it is not found by the browser after install. I can't understand. And running assetic again after install solves the problem. What is assetic changing that is not there in my zip?

Comment: access props ? are they readable ? How does your filestructure look after unzipping ? maybe theres new rootfolder named from the zip itself?

Comment: Edited my question with some permissions and observations: we can see that another JS file has been generated (same goes with CSS). I guess Assetic is not looking for the right files out of the unzip. Any idea on how to correct that? Maybe force assetic to use a given filename?

Answer (score 0):

sorry but (again I'll talk about having to execute command lines) how having to type 7 commands (downaload/wget, unzip, chmod, cp, sql, config) is simpler than making

```
composer create-project marvinlabs/acra-server --prefer-dist acra-server
```

If you add some [post install scripts](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md), you could even auto configure web server / ...

For example, the step of parametere.yml [is already handled](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/composer.json#L25) by a composer script in symfony-standard (https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler).

I would strongly suggest to not use a zip file, but if you want so, here are links to fix your problem of assetic:

- use a [static/fixed output name](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#controlling-the-url-used)
- distribute [prod assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-prod-environment)

By default, assetic **always** generate unique file names, so every dump is another file name.

Comment: Hi, the idea is **not** to type any commands. On shared hosting, composer might not be available (that's the case on mine), you might even not have an SSH access to your server to type any command. Hence the need for a zip file. That said, I agree that both procedures can be done. On top of that, I am new to Symfony, Composer, ... so I consider all advices as good. Thanks a lot for the input.

Comment: Just for comparison, here are the steps for symfony-standard: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#option-2-download-an-archive