# How to save doctrine database schema in a Symfony controller?

Tags: database, symfony, controller, doctrine, actionmethod

I'm using Symfony 2.3 and Doctrine 2 and i need that an user save the schema of a Doctrine Database to a file (*.sql). I need it into an action method and then send the file to the user

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute following command:

```
.app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql >schema.sql
```

And here's the answer how to run `Command` from `Controller`: [How can I run symfony 2 run command from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller)

Answer (score 1):

Just to get you started, this should work in concept. I didn't get to run it, so I assume it might need a little tweaks from your side.

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\CreateSchemaDoctrineCommand;

// your controller

public function myAction()
{
    $command = new CreateSchemaDoctrineCommand();
    $command->setContainer($this->container);
    $input = new ArrayInput(array('--dump-sql' => true));
    $output = new NullOutput();
    $schema = $command->run($input, $output); //This is your schema

    // Write it to a file if you want
    file_put_contents('path/to/schema.sql', $schema);
}
```

**References:**

- Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller)
- PHP [file_put_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)
- [Symfony2 FileSystem](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html)