# Running Symfony2 DEFAULT commands in a controller (NOT custom commands)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I would like to know if it is possible to run Symfony2 default commands within a controller.

I do not mean customized commands: I mean the defaults ones, such as:

```
- generate:bundle
- doctrine:generate:entity
```

And so on.

Comment: to what end? Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I run symfony 2 run command from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller)

Comment: Apart from the dublicate: if it is just because you don't have access to the console, there are plenty of bundles for your needs. For example https://github.com/winzou/ConsoleBundle, there are plenty of other bundles (I used one before, I think it was this one)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. As I say in the post : "I do not mean custom commands : I mean the default ones...". I am trying to create bundle not from the console but from a controller...