# Calling a console command from a controller using the Process component in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am attempting to call a console command from a controller using the Process component in Symfony2 to have it run in the background, however all it does is hang and end up at a white screen. This is an example of what fails:

```
$process = new Process('php app/console list');
$process->setWorkingDirectory($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir().'/../');
$process->run();
print $process->getOutput();
```

I have tried interchanging $process->run() with $process->start() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller

Comment: you need to start a new operating system process with the exec command

Comment: `process->start() ` runs process asynchronously and works for me. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#running-processes-asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [AsyncServiceCallBundle](https://github.com/krlove/async-service-call-bundle), it allows you to execute your application service's methods in background without having to wait until they are finished. Just use it like this:

```
$this->get('krlove.async')->call('service_id', 'method', [$arg1, $arg2, $arg3]);
```

It uses [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/222445/1667170) approach to make such calls asynchronous.