# Run a command as command line from a symfony function

Tags: php, symfony

How run a command as command line from a symfony function?

E.g.

```
C:\SymfonyProject> php app/console my-command --option=my-option
```

I want to run this command from a function. This command export files from a database and place this files in app/Resource/translations folder from Symfony Project.

I.e.

```
public function exportFiles(){ // I want to run command here. }
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run symfony 2 run command from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10497567/how-can-i-run-symfony-2-run-command-from-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Symfony Process component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) for that. The code would look something like this:

```
private function process(OutputInterface $output)
{
    $cmd = 'php app/console my-command --option=my-option';

    $process = new Process($cmd);
    $process->setTimeout(60);

    $process->run(
        function ($type, $buffer) use ($output) {
            $output->write((Process::ERR === $type) ? 'ERR:' . $buffer : $buffer);
        }
);
```

Comment: $output where is defined? It can be a simple file?

Comment: Ah, missed that while copy pasting. $output is a OutputInterface in this case (was running this code in another Symfony Command). But obviously you could just log to a file or whatever you want to do in that case.

Comment: "Could not open input file: app/console"

This error appear in $output file

Path problem?

Comment: Finish:

$cmd = 'php ../app/my-command --option=my-option';

Path problem :D

Thank you so much!