# Prevent test command execution when testing commands in Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, command-line-interface

I have command what purge some storage. I want to test this command. But when I use the CommandTester, it realy purge the storage, I just only to test command not run it. I pretty new in app testing(unit-testing). So I need to somehow mock command object or do like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387857/running-console-command-from-a-symfony-2-test-case)  in second answer(option two)? Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: When you want to do this kind of isolation, you need to mock your object. I can't provide further help as I'm new too unit-tesing but for what I've seen I'm pretty sure this is the way. Hope someone could be more precise than me